# Get notified through Diary or Org-Mode even when Emacs is closed?

Tags: linux, notifications

I am using Emacs on my [Pine Phone](https://www.pine64.org/pinephone/) running Mobian (Debian with a phone shell). What I am looking to do is set up Diary or Org-Mode to set up a calendar and get notifications when Emacs isn't running. I know there are a few things that can have you get a notification while running but I don't want to keep Emacs open all the time to preserve RAM and battery usage. Any ideas?

The reason I was hoping to use Emacs for this is because the default calendar isn't very mobile friendly (super small buttons) and somehow Emacs fits really well by default.

Comment: So is there some calendar app that is running on your phone and can send you notifications? If so, you might be able to sync your Org mode/diary setup to that app. E.g. here's a [link](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html) for some possibilities with Google Calendar - which of course might or might not help in your case.

Comment: That might be exactly what I am looking for, thank you!